# magento: insert content in to predefined block using Custom Layout Update

Tags: php, magento

I have the Ultimo theme on my magento store. There is a predefined static block called 'block_product_secondary_bottom' that when enabled will show up on all products. I am trying to show content in this block's space for select products, and from another defined static block named 'suggested_addons'.

I used the following code in Custom Layout Update and it doesn't work. Any suggestions?

```
<reference name="block_product_secondary_bottom">
    <block type="cms/block" name="suggested_addons">
        <action method="setBlockId"><block_id>suggested_addons</block_id></action>
    </block>    
</reference>
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to include

```
{{block id='suggested_addons'}}
```

in the content of block_product_secondary_bottom.

Comment: block_product_secondary_bottom is a cms static block. Can I put php code in there?

Answer (score 0):

I figured this out myself after 2 hours of trial and error. To add a static block named 'suggested_addons' in place of 'block_product_secondary_bottom' use the following code in custom layout update:

```
<reference name="block_product_secondary_bottom">
<block type="cms/block" name="suggested_addons" as="block_product_secondary_bottom">
    <action method="setBlockId"><block_id>suggested_addons</block_id></action>
</block>
```

The as declaration helped